# Define global grid context in Susy 2

Tags: susy-sass

In susy one it were pretty easy to define scopes where a element changed width depending on a global variable. I'm trying to learn Susy 2 but can not really get the point how it works with breakpoint integration.

I have made some psudocode here to point out what i want to archive

#### Susy SASS maps

```
$small: (
    columns: 4,
);

$medium: (
    columns: 18,
);

$large: (
    columns: 24,
);
```

#### A html element

```
.foo {

    span 2

    at medium
        span 6

    at large
        span 12

}
```

## RESULT I WANT for .foo

- in small = 50% (minus some gutter)
- in medium = 33,3333% (minus some gutter)
- in large = 50% (minus some gutter)

How do you archive this? I've looked at several tutorials but they do not speak about this. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894186/susy-2-0-change-columns-at-breakpoint) talks about something similar. Is it possibly so that we have to constantly tell Susy which layout to use? We could of course say `x **of** something` but i found it quite handy to just define the grids globally and skip the *of* all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Susy 2 almost exactly the way you did in Susy 1. The syntax is a bit more explicit, but the ideas are the same. Assuming you were using `at-breakpoint` in Susy 1, you'll use `susy-breakpoint` in Susy 2 [[see the docs](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#breakpoint)]:

```
$small: 4;
$medium: 18;
$large: 24;

// Susy 1    

$columns: $small;

.foo {
  @include span-columns(2);

  @include at-breakpoint($medium) {
    @include span-columns(6);
  }

  @include at-breakpoint($large) {
    @include span-columns(12);
  }
}

// Susy 2

@include layout($small);

.foo {
  @include span(2);

  @include susy-breakpoint(container($medium), $medium) {
    @include span(6);
  }

  @include susy-breakpoint(container($large), $large) {
    @include span(12);
  }
}
```

You can replace the `container()` arguments with your own breakpoints, as you like. I used the container function because that will mimic the way Susy 1 set breakpoints by default. It's a little less magic, a bit more explicit, and a lot more powerful. You now have the full power of [Breakpoint](http://breakpoint-sass.com/) available for defining your media-queries.